# How to choose boundary conditions for numerical solution of Schrodinger's equation whose solutions are expected to die out "at infinity"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, eigenvalue

I am using the "Shooting method" for solving the TISE with a "reasonably arbitrary" potential in 1D,with boundary conditions such that the eigenfunctions $\psi_n\to0$ as $x\to\infty$(And another boundary condition at finite $x$, which creates no problem).Usually in these cases, without going to infinity, we make the wave function zero deep inside the classically forbidden region ($E<<V(x)$).

If we choose a point which is not deep enough,we are ignoring significant quantum behavior(tunneling),and the eigenvalues are also not much accurate,while if we choose a point which is too much inside the well,the wavefunction becomes (almost) zero **but then diverges**,and hence not normalizable. Also, there is a high chance, that the point at which we can allow the wave function to be zero has direct dependence on $n$,since usually tunneling becomes more significant for higher energy states,and that this depends on the particular potential.So,only an approximate approach(if not a proper algorithm)will suffice.

Obviously, we can choose the point where the wavefunction becomes practically zero by a trial and error procedure,i.e.,--by allowing it to diverge in the first try(taking the boundary point too deep inside the well), and choose,for the second try, the point at which it becomes (almost)zero(in the first try).

I am not looking for a method,to curb the wavefunction-divergence by still allowing the boundary point to be too deep inside, particularly if there is an alternative, to find a more optimal point(less deep but still gives normalizable wavefunction) where the wave function is allowed to die out,without hampering the accuracy of the eigenvalue.

How can we choose such an optimal point?

Comment: Note that shooting method has a great sensitivity to the approximate eigenvalue: you may need very long arithmetic to get deep enough into a potential barrier without getting divergence of wavefunction. And then, accuracy of the eigenvalue will not necessarily be so great, which you'll notice if you e.g. make spatial step smaller.

Comment: If your potential becomes close to a constant at $x\to\infty$, then you may want to approximate it with constant and simply match the exact exponential solution to your shooting solution at the boundary where you switch methods. Or, if your potential grows close to $x$ or $x^2$, then your approximation of choice for the wavefunction could be resp. Airy or Parabolic cylinder functions.

Comment: @Ruslan How can I improve the accuracy of the eigenvalues?
For a morse potential,$E_3=-6.23178$ numerically.where actual value should be -6.25,and no matter how fine I make my spatial grid,the eigenvalue is not becoming more accurate.

Comment: Try using longer arithmetic. I don't know what language you're using, but in Wolfram Language you'd use `SetPrecision` or input your constants like 50-digit 1.5 as ``1.5`50`` (avoiding all machine-precision literals). In Python there's `mpmath` (I didn't use it though as I'm not a pythonist). For C++ look at Boost.Multiprecision, for C there's GMP (GNU multiprecision library).

Comment: I am using Python.I will surely try mpmath,but inaccuracy is in 2nd decimal digit only.Do you think using longer arithmetic will make it alright?

Comment: I think, if your implementation is "theoretically" correct (i.e. for exact arithmetic), then longer arithmetic may reduce accumulation of rounding errors and thus improve your estimate of the eigenvalue. Rounding errors accumulate in the wavefunction, not in eigenvalue, so if you have a lot of steps in the grid, the wavefunction may diverge in the wrong direction simply due to these errors. But no one guarantees that your implementation is correct ;)